# Wrong directory for sipcfg.sip_module_dir

Tags: python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04, qgis

By trying to compile [QGIS](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS) from sources on Ubuntu, there is the file `/opt/QGIS/cmake/FindSIP.py` which content is:

```
import sipconfig

sipcfg = sipconfig.Configuration()
print("sip_version:%06.0x" % sipcfg.sip_version)
print("sip_version_num:%d" % sipcfg.sip_version)
print("sip_version_str:%s" % sipcfg.sip_version_str)
print("sip_bin:%s" % sipcfg.sip_bin)
print("default_sip_dir:%s" % sipcfg.default_sip_dir)
print("sip_inc_dir:%s" % sipcfg.sip_inc_dir)
# SIP 4.19.10+ has new sipcfg.sip_module_dir
if hasattr(sipcfg, "sip_module_dir"):
    print("sip_module_dir:%s" % sipcfg.sip_module_dir)
else:
    print("sip_module_dir:%s" % sipcfg.sip_mod_dir)
```

In Python3.6, the last `if/else` statement prints:

```
sip_module_dir:/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
```

But the string `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` doesn't match an existing directory (it is probably part of why I encountered the error: 
`python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis__core.dir/build.make:537: recipe for target 'python/core/sip_corepart0.cpp' failed' failed` during build process).

I either have:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

or

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

And it's only in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` that I have some 'sip' related files (the other directory gives no results):

```
$ find . -iname "*sip*"
./twisted/protocols/__pycache__/sip.cpython-36.pyc
./twisted/protocols/sip.py
./twisted/test/test_sip.py
./twisted/test/__pycache__/test_sip.cpython-36.pyc
./sipconfig.py
./sip.pyi
./sipconfig_nd6.py
./sipdistutils.py
./__pycache__/sipconfig_nd6.cpython-36.pyc
./__pycache__/sipdistutils.cpython-36.pyc
./__pycache__/sipconfig.cpython-36.pyc
./sip.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I guess there is something to fix within 'sip' itself but don't know where exactly, neither how to do that.

**More information;**
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits
Python: 3.6.7
Sip: 4.19.7